# Regular expression with special character inside CSV with quoted matches

Tags: asp.net, regex, parsing, csv, c#-4.0

I tried and this is the best I could come up with, need a fresh eye or help to finish this job.

Expression:

```
\"[a-zA-Z\s0-9\.\']*\"
```

Input String Data:

```
BOL,"AWBH0876356","HMM","H0010","BEANR","BEANR","AEJEA","BHBAH","","","T","S","","","F","N","","FCL/FCL","BE","","","","","","","","SUNNYLAND DISTRIBUTION NV","EVERDONGENLAAN 12 2300 TURNHOUT","","","INTERNATIONAL AGENCIES CO LTD","BUILDING 406, ROAD 4308, BLOCK 343, MANAMA BAHRAIN","","INTERNATIONAL AGENCIES CO LTD","BUILDING 406, ROAD 4308, BLOCK 343, MANAMA BAHRAIN","","","","","","","N/A","770000",""SHIPPER'S LOAD & COUNT, SAID TO BE:" 1X20'DC CONTAINER S.T.C 1650 CARTON OF JUICES FREIGHT PREPAID","1650","CARTONS","CTN","","","1","1","2.2","21615.0","23815.0","0","0","0","0","","",""
```

I need to ignore the first word (`BOL`) and comma, which is working, but I am stuck with matches which have special character (`'`,`"`) in them.

Below match is an issue, for example:

```
""SHIPPER'S LOAD & COUNT, SAID TO BE:" 1X20'DC CONTAINER S.T.C 1650 CARTON OF JUICES FREIGHT PREPAID"
```

Comment: There isn't really a proper standard for CSV, but no method I know of quoting in CSV files would produce your output. I would say that the process generating these CSV files needs to be fixed in order to get a parseable file.

Comment: Thank you! But I am afraid that is not an option right now, otherwise it would have made things much easier for me and I would have had the solution already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current problem with your regex (and the string to be parsed) is that it doesn't accept that there is a quote inside a value and the string has. Maybe, you could specify that there can be a quote inside, but then, the closing quote should only be before a comma or at the end of the string, and you can do that with a positive lookhead:

```
".*?"(?=,|$)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uM6mA3/1)

`".*?"` matches the value while `(?=,|$)` ensures there's either a comma after it or the end of the string (indicated by `$`).

Note that if your string has value containing a quote character followed by a comma, the above regex won't work.

In that case, what I usually do is count the number of matches. If this exceeds the number I expect, I put the original line separately so I can look at them one by one (that will involve some manual intervention, but that's better than ending up with lots of errors!).

If all the problems come from a single column, then you could change your script so that it will 'merge' values from *i* to *j* (*i* being the column number where the first issue occurs and *j* being the next one) until there's an appropriate number of values.

Comment: Might be better to use `"(?:""|.)*?"(?=,|$)` if you have a "more proper" csv with some anomalies for the truly escaped quotes.

Comment: It gets better than that. Some CSV files use a backslash to quote a double quote, so you then need to use `(?:""|\\"|.)`.

Comment: `(?:["\\]"|.)` easier (and tiny bit faster) like this @Phylogenesis :) And you can add any other escape character the person who created the csv into the character class. Seriously though, I prefer tab delimited's or pipe delimited's. You are much less likely to run into these within texts so it's easier to parse.

Comment: Fair enough. In the end, I much prefer tab-separated files because of parsing issues like this and the non-standardized nature of CSV. (Which is exactly what your edited comment now says!)

Comment: Thank you Jerry, this is awesome. You probably are the god of regular expressions (at-least to me). Exact number of values returned, i.e. 60 :)

Comment: @Hitin I have still a way to go :) And I really don't want to go too far because the more complex things usually are unique to a particular language (that I probably will never use!) Thank you, and I'm glad that you are being able to parse the csv.

Comment: @Jerry just another thing I am having issue with, When I assign expression to a string variable I am using "\" to escape quotes, i.e "\".*?\"(?=,|$)", which returns each value as "\"BOL\"" , what can I do to ignore this?

Comment: @Hitin If it's C#, you should be able to use declare the expression as a literal string with the at sign: `@".*?"(?=,|$)`. Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand your issue. Your match result has `\"`? Do the backslashes still remain if you output them to a new file?

Comment: @Jerry Its all good, I was checking the matches on runtime, as soon as I right them into file, there are no backslash. As I am suppose to write them to MS-SQL database, I hope there won't be any backslash when I insert data in the table. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Hitin Ok and yes, sometimes just to distinguish between a quote to denote a string and a literal quote, the engine will display the backslash. Cool then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=,))"(?!,")(.+?)"(?=,"|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/4

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't parse the following *properly quoted* CSV line: `"Field","Another "","" field""","More Fields"`. When you receive an invalid file, it's very difficult to put together a regex that is going to cope with it *and* valid files at the same time.

Comment: @Phylogenesis the exmaple you gave isnt this d expected output ? https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/5

Comment: No, `""` is considered a quoted `"` in CSV. There are only 3 fields in my example.